# Android Studio Java Class has a dropdown

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having an issue in Android Studio where I have a class in the Project tab, but next to it there is a dropdown arrow and the outer class says "class".java and it drops down and inside is a normal class that looks like all the rest.

[image]

How do I get it to look normal again?

Comment: It's a subclass of your Utility class

Comment: @Apurva and his question is he doesn't want to see that dropdown arrow but just a Utility class, how he can get the look as normal class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a Util class in your Utility.java file.

Are you able to just rename all instances of Util to Utility? Or change the filename to Util.java.

Comment: But his question is he doesn't want to see that dropdown arrow but just a Utility class!

Comment: The whole reason for the dropdown is that there a public class declaration in a compilation unit not of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a nested `Util` class inside the outer `Utility` class. Get rid of the inner class if you don't need it and move its functions to the parent `Utility` class.